# How to have app shortcut in menu bar mac

Tags: macos, automator

I made an applescript and want it to be in the menu bar. So when I click it in the menu bar, it will run. I don't want it in my dock. How can I do that. Can I do it in my script or can I do it with an app that puts app shortcuts in the menu bar. I am on OSX Yosemite.